# filesystem::create_directories error when using __TIME__

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a folder and use the current time as its name. For this I have tried the following:

```
using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
int main()
{
    
  auto dirname = fs::current_path() / __TIME__;  
  std::filesystem::create_directories(dirname);


}
```

which results in
`Unhandled exception at 0x75F99862 in prime.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::filesystem::filesystem_error at memory location 0x00AFF930.`

I have tried to replace `__TIME_`_ with `__DATE__` and it works as intended(obv it uses the date not the time).
What alternative do I have or what should I do to make this work? I don't quite care about the format of the time, it could be date/time, time/date, just time or any other format that includes time.
Thank you.

Comment: I have tried other approaches for getting time(using ```std::chrono::system_clock::now``` or ```std::time_t ct = std::time(0);``` but these failed too

Comment: You want to use _compilation time_ as the name of the directory or _current time_?

Comment: @KamilCuk anything would work as long as it is a form of time

Comment: Couldn't reproduce on linux (GCC 10)

Comment: The time contains a character (the colon) that’s invalid in a Windows filename.

Comment: Are filenames allowed to have the ':' character in them on the specified filesystem?

Comment: @JCWasmx86 it just worked? do you have a new folder which's name is the time?

Comment: Yes, it worked.

Comment: @G.M. I get the same error when I tried ```  std::filesystem::create_directories("./a:sd");``` so I think this might be the problem

Comment: @molbdnilo this is awkwardly stupid. This is one step closer for me to ditch Windows forever. Thank you